# Passing Object into Class Function doesn't work if Dim object VBA

Tags: vba, class

I have 2 class modules:  CAccount and CAccounts

CAccounts has a function to add a CAccount to a private collection using:

```
    Private pAccounts As New Collection
    Public Function add_account(value As CAccount)
        pAccounts.Add value
    End Function
```

I have a Main() subroutine

```
Sub main()  
        'dim Accounts As CAccounts  <---- if i uncomment this i get run time error
        Set Accounts = New CAccounts

            Set accnt = New CAccount
            Accounts.add_account (accnt)

end sub
```

If i dimension the CAccounts object i get the following error message:

*Run-time error '438':  Object doesn't support this property or method*

However if i set the CAccounts object without Dim (i.e. VBA assumes CAccounts is a variant) then it works.

I don't understand why VBA has an issue with dimensioning the object beforehand.

Does anyone understand this stuff well enought to explain what is going on here ?  Thanks !

Comment: `Accounts.add_account (accnt)` Remove the parenthesis. ;Correct line should be `Accounts.add_account accnt` Adding the parenthesis force the parameter to be passed by value.

Comment: @Vincent G but it works with parenthesis if we comment out Dim so parenthesis per se is not forcing a value instead of object.  If we remove parenthesis as suggested we get "Compile Error:  ByRef argument mismatch"

Comment: `dim Accounts As New CAccounts` wouldn't make `Set` line not needed ? (asking, i am genuinely not sure)

Comment: Where are you running this? If I copy your code into 3 modules (the two class modules + `main` in separate module) in Excel, add `Option Explicit` in all three modules, add the `Dim` statement and remove the parenthesis like @VincentG suggested, it works fine.

Comment: @Vincent G i have added `Option Explicit` to match you and this also causes it to work.  Curious this should be the case as i thought the absence of `Option Explicit` would give more flexibility

Comment: If you don't declare it, `accnt` will be a `Variant` when `add_account` expects a `CAccount` object.

Comment: @Olle Sjorgen thank you very much for your responses.   `Option Explicit' and removing parentheses works well, thank you.    However it also worked fine when no option explicit and didn't declare it.   It was only when no option explicit and declared it, with or without parenthesis, which casued an issue...  which seems a bit of a mystery... as i had declared and set a CAccount object and was feeding that in.

Comment: @Christopher you are welcome - I always use `Option Explicit`, it takes some of the guesswork out of VBA!